# How to make an image appear over another image when mouse hovers with css3?

Tags: html, css, hover

Hey I would like a magnifying glass or some image to pop over another image when on mouseover like this website - http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/ When you hover over an image an image appears over it. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Not sure if you need any code but here's my css for the img tag:

```
img {
width: 600px;
height: 342px;
border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Comment: They position an element directly over it, and then fade in the opacity on mouseover using jQuery.

Comment: [Here, this is the same code they used, I just used pure CSS with no jQuery to achieve it, however you'll see there's no `fadeIn animation`, just instantaneous display.](http://jsfiddle.net/5snqw/)

Comment: Cheers man doesnt work though :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with

**HTML**

```
<div id="yourImage" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#yourImage {
 background-image: url('image1.jpg');
}


#yourImage:hover {
 background-image: url('overimage.jpg'), url('image1.jpg');
}
```

Comment: How do you center the hover image on to the actual image?

Comment: Each background which is separated by coma you can styled like normal background so you can use just " `...url('overimage.jpg') center, url...`

Comment: This is pretty cool, I didn't even know css could do this! Gotta get rid of a lotta jquery i used to use haha

Answer (score 3):

There is a [jquery plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/) for this.

The first effect is what you're looking for.

Comment: aww okay thank you, is it possible to do it with css3 only at all?

Comment: Well, yes you can but it won't be cross browser compatible as you know. My guess is to use an image behind the content div, and fade it in using [css3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) on the container's opacity property

Comment: Click on the link I gave you, then find the download button in the page and download it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/magnify.html). I think it uses only CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the CSS `position` attribute, so you can have both elements on the same place.
And then just chang the `opacity` of the hover image.

Comment: @André Catita It won't have the transitive effect though

Answer (score 0):

@Mateusz has the best answer, but I would improve upon that by adding the css transition something along the lines of this:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
```

Comment: Cheers man :) do you know how to centre the hover image over the actual image? At the moment it's at the top left

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="your-img">
    <div class="your-hover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.your-img {
    width: 300px; /* your image width and height here */
    height: 225px;
    background-image: url('../img/image_01.png');
}
.your-hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 225px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    background-image: url('../img/image-hover_01.png');
}
.your-hover:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
}
```

`filter: alpha` is for IE, I hope it helps.