# How can I make an image overlay using CSS so that I can have a pencil icon to edit info, like Facebook has?

Tags: css, html, hover, overlay

I'm writing a simple web app in which I have pictures of people with some information about them displayed underneath.  I would like to have a pencil icon appear above the image on mouseover so the user can click the pencil to enter edit mode.  I've pieced together most of what I want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>pencil-tooltip</title>
    <style>
      .picture {
        position: relative;
        width: -moz-max-content;
        width: -webkit-max-content;
        width: max-content;
      }
      .picture img:hover +.pencil {
        display:inline;
      }
      .pencil {
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        margin:5px;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="picture">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRNEQ.png">
      <span class="pencil" onclick="console.log('hello')">
        <svg width="16px" height="16px" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1">
          <path d="M29.395,2.58C27.75,0.937,25.584,0,23.449,0c-1.801,0-3.459,0.668-4.67,1.877l-4.867,4.904  c-0.015,0.014-0.032,0.023-0.047,0.038c-0.008,0.008-0.013,0.019-0.021,0.026l0.002,0.002L3.517,17.256  c-0.476,0.473-0.821,1.062-1.013,1.705l-2.349,8.508C0.153,27.492,0,28.16,0,28.5C0,30.432,1.569,32,3.504,32  c0.385,0,1.13-0.184,1.157-0.188l8.478-2.229c0.644-0.191,1.229-0.539,1.705-1.016l15.263-15.383  C32.883,10.406,32.57,5.75,29.395,2.58z M16.014,23.795c-0.082-0.902-0.337-1.787-0.719-2.627l9.455-9.454  c0.578,1.826,0.281,3.736-0.986,5.004c-0.008,0.008-0.018,0.013-0.025,0.021l0.014,0.013l-7.728,7.79  C16.025,24.293,16.037,24.049,16.014,23.795z M14.793,20.256c-0.373-0.613-0.797-1.205-1.322-1.729  c-0.611-0.611-1.312-1.09-2.044-1.492l9.532-9.532c0.748,0.332,1.465,0.805,2.098,1.438c0.541,0.539,0.959,1.143,1.281,1.771  L14.793,20.256z M10.486,16.562c-0.926-0.373-1.896-0.586-2.868-0.599l7.703-7.762c1.179-1.15,2.896-1.481,4.587-1.062  L10.486,16.562z M4.167,29.873C4.058,29.898,3.719,29.984,3.489,30C2.667,29.99,2,29.322,2,28.5  c0.012-0.168,0.079-0.457,0.102-0.562l1.053-3.814c1.143-0.031,2.373,0.414,3.34,1.383c0.982,0.98,1.444,2.234,1.394,3.391  L4.167,29.873z M8.874,28.637c-0.024-1.342-0.57-2.738-1.672-3.838C6.16,23.756,4.796,23.154,3.436,23.1l0.996-3.607  c0.072-0.24,0.215-0.477,0.391-0.684c2.006-1.436,5.091-1.012,7.234,1.133c2.267,2.266,2.617,5.586,0.871,7.568  c-0.116,0.061-0.233,0.119-0.359,0.156L8.874,28.637z M28.691,11.772l-1.684,1.697c0-0.226,0.027-0.443,0.006-0.674  c-0.176-1.935-1.078-3.806-2.543-5.269c-1.629-1.63-3.789-2.565-5.928-2.571l1.656-1.67C21.027,2.458,22.184,2,23.449,2  c1.609,0,3.262,0.728,4.533,1.995c1.193,1.191,1.904,2.671,2.006,4.168C30.082,9.56,29.621,10.841,28.691,11.772z" fill="#333333" id="pen"/>
        </svg>
      </span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've used these prior Stackoverflow questions as sources to implement the above:

[How to make an image appear over another image when mouse hovers with css3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384523/how-to-make-an-image-appear-over-another-image-when-mouse-hovers-with-css3)

[Show image over another image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108112/show-image-over-another-image-on-hover)

[How do I make another image appear on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184456/how-do-i-make-another-image-appear-on-hover)

[Show image over another image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108112/show-image-over-another-image-on-hover)

I have two problems.  One:  There is some kind of rendering issue when I mouse over the pencil icon.  If I move the mouse around on top of the pencil it flickers in and out.  This is very unattractive (I've tried it in four different browsers).  Second:  the `onclick` action doesn't work.  It does work, however, if I remove these parts of the code:

```css
.picture img:hover +.pencil {
  display:inline;
}
.pencil {
  display:none;
}
```

Any solutions or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the hover and click issue you can use

```
.picture:hover > .pencil {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Wow!  The CSS child selector, that works perfectly, thanks!  -- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 1):

i added an overlay and centered your pencil, should work if this is what you're looking for. changed css on the pencil to:

```
    top:calc(50% - 10px);
    right:calc(50% - 20px);
```

also added the overlay in the html:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2p17yhxz/